# Why does this distribution function depend on time and not temperature?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, wick-rotation

When reading [Sterile neutrino hot, warm, and cold dark matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0101524) I came across the following momentum distribution function for a neutrino species $\alpha$:

$$\tag{5.8} f(p,t) = \frac{1}{e^{E(p)/T + \eta_{\nu_\alpha}}+1}$$

where $\eta_{\nu_\alpha}= \mu_{\nu_\alpha }/T$ and $E(p) \approx p$.

**Why is the function $f$ a function of variables $p$ (momentum) and $t$ (time) when the RHS shows that the function only depends on $p$ and on $T$ (temperature)?**

On another article [Dodelson-Widrow production of sterile neutrino Dark Matter with non-trivial initial abundance](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1475-7516/2016/04/003/pdf) it is stated that $f(p,t)$ and $f(p,T)$ are equivalent.

**But how can this be so? How can temperature and time be equivalent?**

Comment: I'd wager that it's just a typo, and that they meant to put $T$ instead of $t$.  Is the equation written the same way in the version published in PRD?

Answer (score 1):

I am too low on reputation to comment, so I post it as an answer.

This is not my field of expertise (at all!) but I came across an idea that [seems similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation#The_path_integral_and_the_partition_function).

Also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation):

> Wick rotation connects statistical mechanics to quantum mechanics by replacing inverse temperature $1 / ( k_B T )$ with imaginary time $it/\hbar$."

Maybe this can lead someone to an answer.